Change DateTime output or Format the order
I am using Blazor and I have an this input date field.
<div class="input-group">
    <InputDate name="To Date" class="form-control rounded-2" @bind-Value="auditForm.toDate" @bind-Value:format="yyyy/MM/dd" TValue="DateTime" />
</div>

And I am parsing the value to the parent via parameter where I am using the values to display a certain form.
This is the code block on the parent.
    // Method to handle form submission from child component
    private async Task HandleFilterSubmitted(AuditForm auditForm)
    {
        // Update search parameters
        searchType = auditForm.searchType;
        searchCriteria = auditForm.searchCriteria;
        fromDate = auditForm.fromDate;
        toDate = auditForm.toDate;

 
        // Reload audit trail with updated parameters
        await LoadAuditTrail();

        // Log the values of the AuditForm object
        _logger.LogInformation("Search Type: {SearchType}, Search Criteria: {SearchCriteria}, From Date: {FromDate}, To Date: {ToDate}",
        auditForm.searchType, auditForm.searchCriteria, auditForm.fromDate, auditForm.toDate);
        
    }

I would like the DateTime format to be parsed in this specific order: yyyy/MM/dd not the default dd/MM/yyyy
This is my console output of how it should not look like:

I have tried using the bind-Value:format method
I tried converting it to a string and it will not work because my server is expecting a DateTime object not a string.
I have read on plenty articles but they are all converting to string which is what I do not want to do.
I want to change the formatting from dd/MM/yyyy to yyyy/MM/dd when the data is being assigned here:
        // Update search parameters
        searchType = auditForm.searchType;
        searchCriteria = auditForm.searchCriteria;
        fromDate = auditForm.fromDate; //HERE
        toDate = auditForm.toDate; //HERE


You don't really format dates.

Neither DateTime nor DateTimeOffset have formats. Formatting comes into play when you parse and when you - well - format (into a string) and only then. Which happens when you put them into a log message. If not explicitly instructed otherwise, they will be formatted by the default method.

Think of it as a number. Let's say 6. A 6 is a 6 is a 6, but you could write it as "6.0", "6", "6,0" (in different culture), "006", "06.000" ... same value.
